# Datatables won't reload json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

Not only should this be a straightforward operation but I'm following the [documentation](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) as well. I have an ajax call that returns a `json` data set. I've cleared the table successfully but when the `success` method is called nothing happens. The `console` statement shows that data is being returned... however the table remains empty. Any idea why?

**JS**

```
    $('#SortByCoverage').click(function () {
        var table = $('#theTable').DataTable();
        table.fnClearTable();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Question2',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);                    
                $("#thetable").dataTable({
                    "aaData": data,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        {title:"AdId"},
                        {title:"BrandId"},
                        {title:"BrandName"},
                        {title:"NumPages"},
                        {title:"Position"}
                        ]                        
                });
            }
        });
```

**Server Side Code**

```
    public JsonResult Question2()
    {
        var ads = _client.GetAdDataByDateRange(new DateTime(2011, 1, 1), new DateTime(2011, 4, 1));
        var json = ads.Where(x => x.Position.Equals("Cover") && x.NumPages >= (decimal)0.5).Select(x => new{
            AdId = x.AdId,
            BrandId = x.Brand.BrandId,
            BrandName = x.Brand.BrandName,
            NumPages = x.NumPages,
            Position = x.Position
        });

        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Sample Data (client side)**

[image]

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments I misspelled the element name `dataTable` in the `success` callback. However, now I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot reinitialise DataTable. To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy

1. Do I really have to destroy the table, once it's clear, to reload the data?
2. I added the `bRetrieve` and `bDestroy`. This got rid of the error but still no new data loaded into the table.

   ```
       $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("Question2", "Home")',
           type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               $("#theTable").dataTable({
                   //"bRetrieve": true,
                   "bDestroy": true,
                   "aaData": data,
                   "aoColumns": [
                       {title:"AdId"},
                       {title:"BrandId"},
                       {title:"BrandName"},
                       {title:"NumPages"},
                       {title:"Position"}
                       ]                        
               });
           }
       });
   ```

Comment: In the top of your fn you're selecting `"#theTable"` and in your success fn you're selecting `"#thetable"` --- is that the same element? Typo?

Comment: No I'm an idiot and that's a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a little different, see how:

```
var theTable = $("#thetable").dataTable({
    "aaData": [],
    "aoColumns": [
        {data:"AdId"},
        {data:"BrandId"},
        {data:"BrandName"},
        {data:"NumPages"},
        {data:"Position"}
        ]                        
}).DataTable();

$('#SortByCoverage').click(function () {    
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Question2',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
              theTable.clear().draw();
              table.rows.add(data)
                .draw();                    

            }
        });
```

Comment: This gave me the error `Uncaught TypeError: theTable.clear is not a function`

Comment: I've mispelled #thetable.. and do you know which dataTable version are you using? later note, you must run this on jquery ready event.

Comment: Ah, I see what the deal is. There was a typo in my post and `thetable` element should be `theTable`. Once I make that change, however I get the error `Cannot reinitialise DataTable. To retrieve DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy`

Comment: I'm sorry, change last dataTable, to "DataTable" (caps D) (i've updated my example)

Comment: I needed to add `bDestroy: true` to the `.dataTable` but this worked. Thanks!